# Difference in func with receiver and param golang

Tags: go, marshalling, gob

I try to create marshal func for struct Item.

So the question is, why the first example gives stackoverflow for goroutine and second works correctly?

1. Call method with receiver

```
type Item struct{
  a int
}

func some(items []Item){
   for _,i:=range items{
      buf,err:=i.MarhsalBinary()
      fmt.Println(buf.Bytes(), err)
}

func (i Item) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
   var (
       buf bytes.Buffer
       err error
   )
   if err = gob.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(i); err != nil { // endless loop here
       return nil, err
   }

   return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```

2. This is pass by value.

```
type Item struct{
  a int
}

func some(items []Item){
   for _,i:=range items{
      buf,err:=MarhsalBinary(i)
      fmt.Println(buf.Bytes(), err)
}

func MarshalBinary(i Item) ([]byte, error) {
   var (
       buf bytes.Buffer
       err error
   )
   if err = gob.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(i); err != nil { // works correctly
       return nil, err
   }

   return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#pkg-overview *"Gob can encode a value of any type implementing the GobEncoder or [`encoding.BinaryMarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#BinaryMarshaler) interfaces **by calling the corresponding method**, in that order of preference."* -- That means that `Encode(i)` calls `i.MarshalBinary` which calls `Encode(i)` which calls `i.MarshalBinary` which calls `Encode(i)` which calls `i.MarshalBinary` ... ad infinitum.

Comment: Ah, got it. So I just need to change the name of my func in order to make it work correctly.

Comment: Method, yes. For example change `func (i Item) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {` to `func (i Item) MarshalToBinary() ([]byte, error) {` and you should be good to go.